# create with has_many through association gets NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3%3a-tagging) and am stuck in the Tagging part. Basically I have articles that can have a list of tags. As one article can has multiple tags and vice versa, there is an additional `taggings` model, through which this association is modelled. Here are the models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :articles, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :article
end
```

and the migrations:

```
def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.text :body
        t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :tags do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :taggings do |t|
        t.references :tag, index: true
        t.references :article, index: true
        t.timestamps
    end
```

There's also an `article_controller` with (amongst others):

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Now, as the tutorial suggets, when I try to create a new `tag` with the rails console for an article, I get a `NoMethodError` for a `nil:NilClass`:

```
head :011 > Article.first.tags.create(name: "tag")
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", ...], ["name", "tag"], ["updated_at", ...]]
  SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("article_id", "created_at", "tag_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["article_id", 1], ["created_at", ...], ["tag_id", 7], ["updated_at", ...]]
 (0.6ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

So it seems to me, as if the `tag` entry is created, as well as the correct `taggings` entry, but apparently at some point it struggles to find the correct `tag`, hence the error. Am I right? How can I fix this?

I found a lot of questions on SO regarding this kind of error, but each was caused by some problem I couldn't relate to mine...

UPDATE:

`reloading` or restarting the rails console has no effect.

Here is the error backtrace, with *path* as `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record`:

```
from path/associations/has_many_association.rb:81:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
from path/associations/has_many_association.rb:77:in `has_cached_counter?'
from path/associations/has_many_association.rb:85:in `update_counter'
from path/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:66:in `insert_record'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:463:in `block (2 levels) in create_record'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:367:in `add_to_target'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:461:in `block in create_record'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
from path/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
from path/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
from path/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
from path/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:460:in `create_record'
from path/associations/collection_association.rb:121:in `create'
from path/associations/collection_proxy.rb:260:in `create'
from (irb):14
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you write the error backtrace?

Comment: You might have to use `reload!` in your console to make it re-read all the files of your app, and make it aware of all the changes that were made.

Comment: Try like this `a= Article.first` and then `a.tags.create(name: "tag")`.

Comment: `reloading` has no effect. I also tried exiting and restarting the rails console to no avail

Comment: @Pavan: this gets the same result...

Comment: Yes, same error and same error backtrace

Comment: @mdesantis: added error backtrace

Comment: Sounds weird... did you run the migration (using `rake db:migrate`)?

Comment: And: do you have a counter somewhere in your models? It seems somewhat related

Comment: @mdesantis: yes, I did run the migration. What do you mean by counter?

Comment: I mean an [has_many :counter_cache](http://docs.rubydocs.org/ruby-2-1-2-rails-4-1-1/Rails%204.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) or similar, it seems related looking at the backtrace

Comment: You're right, it somehow seems related, but adding it (and adding the according column) didn't change anything. Same error, exact same backtrace...

Comment: I'm giving up for now. I basically did the tutorial anew and left out any for this functionality uneeded part, but it has still the same error. I also tried some of the options mentioned in the rubydocs to no effect. Maybe some part of my rails installation/configuration is messed up, so maybe I happen to run again into this problem and hopefully then find a solution which I can post here... But thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @mdesantis: as posted in my answer, I got it to work by switching ruby versions...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it to work by switching ruby versions. I was using `ruby-head`, which is `ruby 2.2.0dev`. Switched back to `ruby-2.1.1`, now it works without errors. Should've probably tried that earlier...

Maybe this could help others facing similar errors.

Comment: Thanks, I lost a couple of hours on it. I fix it updating with ruby ruby-2.2.1 and rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 12):

Upgrade to Rails 4.0.13 (or later) or downgrading to Ruby 2.1.1 solves the problem.

Comment: Ruby `2.1.8` solves the problem as well (which I needed because of the supported ruby versions on Heroku) , but nevertheless, your answer has directed me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: downgrading from Rails `4.0.2` to `4.0.13` works. I was using activerecord `4.0.2` and I downgraded to `4.0.13`. Also my ruby version is `2.3.3p222`

Answer (score 5):

FYI, I can confirm this is an issue with ActiveRecord and Ruby 2.2.  I was using ActiveRecord 3.2 and since changing to the 3-2-stable branch, the issue is gone.  I believe this is fixed now in 4.x branches.  I have raised an issue for this at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18991.

Comment: I can double-confirm this. I was trying  to use **Rails 3.2.21** with **Ruby 2.2.0** and no worky. Switched to the **Rails 3-2-stable** branch and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in activerecord 4.1.0 with has_cached_counter? and ruby 2.2. It was fixed on activerecord 4.1.2.

I got it to work by switching rails versions from 4.1.0 to 4.1.2.