# RoR: NoMethodError when executing delete_all for a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My classes are as follows, with Customer inheriting from User using the single-table inheritance approach. User has attributes name and email while Order has destination.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Customer < User
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Based on the following snippet of code run using the Rails console

```
c = Customer.create
c.orders << Order.create
c.orders.delete_all
```

Executing the delete_all function in the last line results in NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass. However, the following works.

```
c = Customer.new
c.orders << Order.create
c.orders.delete_all
```

The same works perfectly find on a friend's computer. Anyone have any idea what might be going on? Might it be related to a bug in the version of something I'm using?

Stack trace

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-    4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:81:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:77:in `has_cached_counter?'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:85:in `update_counter'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:125:in `delete_records'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in `remove_records'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `block in delete_or_destroy'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `delete_or_destroy'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:230:in `delete'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:160:in `delete_all'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:422:in `delete_all'
from (irb):6
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you precise to which model `name` is an attributes ? It looks like the error doesn't come from the delete_all method

Comment: Can you give a stack trace of the exception and the full source of User, Customer and Order. There seems to be some active record callback or validation issue. The difference between `new` and `create` is that `create` immediately runs all callbacks, validations and saves the object in database, whereas `new` only creates the object in memory.

Comment: @Chambeur I did specify it above, but perhaps I wasn't clear enough.
User fields => name, email
Order fields => destination

Comment: @OlegK. The full source code is almost exactly the same; the only things I did not write in the above are functions to check the state of the object. There are no self-written callbacks in the full source either.

Comment: @keylime it crashes in `has_many_association.rb::cached_counter_attribute_name`, so there seems to be some cached counter on customer's `orders` and there's something wrong with the counter. It works for `new` record because it does not perform that callbacks unless the record is saved in DB. Can you find the `orders` counter in the source? it should look line `has_many :orders, counter_cache: :true`

Comment: @OlegK. Thanks for your suggestion, but since the I have discovered that problem is indeed one to do with the Ruby version, I will simply downgrade for now. Even if I do find the source of the problem, it will likely take a lot of effort to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you were right about the problem about the ruby version.
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568084/create-with-has-many-through-association-gets-nomethoderror-undefined-method-n).

The guy had a similar problem and he fixed it by switching his ruby version from ruby-2.2.0 to ruby-2.1.1.

If it's not the ruby version, it could be the ActiveRecord Version.

Comment: True enough, it was the Ruby version. My friend's computer was running 2.1.5 so I tried downgrading to that and it works find now. Thank you.

Comment: Another option of course is to up your rails version in the Gemfile. I tried switching my reference to rails to gem 'rails', '4.2.3' and ran bundle update and that fixed the problem

Comment: For those using 4.1, I upgraded to 4.1.16 and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

This is the Rails issue with Ruby 2.2.2: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18991 . It's closed and fixed in 3.2.22).

Answer (score 1):

Try updating you Customer class association with

```
has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
```

or

```
has_many :orders, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Depending on what you want to achieve.

`:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.

`:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database without executing callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

for [delete_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class)

**for example**

```
 Post.delete_all("person_id = 5 AND (category = 'Something' OR category = 'Else')")
  Post.delete_all(["person_id = ? AND (category = ? OR category = ?)", 5, 'Something', 'Else'])
```

for [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class)

**for example**

```
 Person.destroy_all("last_login < '2004-04-04'")
  Person.destroy_all(:status => "inactive")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no inverse associations and Rails fails to resolve the order's customer when updating the cached counters. Try this:

```
class Customer < User
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :customer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :orders
end
```