# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass in FileController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error with this code, but I can not figure out how the name method is being called.

file_controller.rb:

```
91| def destroy
92|  r = Module::Model.find(params[:id])
93|  r.parts.each{|p| p.destroy }
94|  r.destroy
95|  render :nothing => true, :status => 200
96| end
```

The error is being thrown on the "r.destroy" line.

Here is the error:

```
!! There was an error ( > _ < )
!!
!! Params: {"action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"module/controller", "id"=>"7156"}
!!
!! ERROR !!
!! NoMethodError
!!
!! /path/to/file_controller.rb:94:in `destroy'
!! undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
!!
```

Additionally Requested:

```
class Scheduling::TimeOffRequest < Scheduling::Connection
  include Logged
  self.table_name = 'time_off_requests'

  has_many :parts, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :type, foreign_key: 'request_type_id'
  belongs_to :state, foreign_key: 'request_state_id'

  #****************************************************************************
  module STATE
    PEND = 1
    DENY = 2
    APPROVE = 3
    APPROVE_MOD = 4
  end
  #****************************************************************************
  def self.display
    mysql.query
  end
end
```

Stack Trace:

```
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:80:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:103:in `inverse_updates_counter_cache?'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:113:in `delete_records'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in `remove_records'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `block in delete_or_destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:253:in `block in transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:476:in `using_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:225:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:462:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:224:in `run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `delete_or_destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:247:in `destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:170:in `destroy_all'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:26:in `handle_dependency'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:97:in `has_many_dependent_for_parts'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:387:in `_run__2188473118504979458__destroy__callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:289:in `destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:265:in `block in destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:253:in `block in transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:476:in `using_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:225:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:462:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:224:in `run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:265:in `destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/persistence.rb:25:in `block in destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:476:in `using_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:225:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:462:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:224:in `run_queries_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/shard_tracking.rb:30:in `run_on_shard'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.5/lib/octopus/persistence.rb:25:in `destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/releases/1435700629/app/controllers/scheduling/pto_controller.rb:94:in `destroy'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__1437761400294135477__process_action__callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__607729009339104246__call__callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.0.288/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
!! /usr/local/rvm/ge/2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:85:in `process_request'
!! /usr/local/rvm/ge/2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:155:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
!! /usr/local/rvm/ge/2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
!! /usr/local/rvm/ge/2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
!! /usr/local/rvm/ge/2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Is anyone able to answer why #destroy is calling #name?

Comment: Did you check the destroy method in Module::ModelsController

Comment: Perhaps there's a before_destroy callback?  Look in the proper stack trace rather than whatever you've got telling you about the error there.  Go from the top, ignoring anything pointing into gems or other library folders:  look for references to code in your app.

Comment: Yeah, I bet it's in a callback

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: The first code block is from that file.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: There are no callbacks for this model (at least that I can tell). I will post model in a moment.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I get it, its not a callback issue. This is an issue with ActiveRecord and Ruby 2.2

You can fix it by switching the ruby version from ruby-2.2.0 to ruby-2.1.3 or rails version from 4.0.0 to 4.1.2

Check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409323/ror-nomethoderror-when-executing-delete-all-for-a-has-many-relationship)

Answer (score -1):

aha!

```
!! /var/www/projects/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:80:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
```

told you it was a callback :)

counter_cache sets up a callback to update a field when an associated record changes.  Presumably you've got a counter_cache or similar call in one of the associated models?  Something about the way this is set up assumes that the model that's just been deleted is still there.  Are you doing counter_cache anywhere?  If so then add the code for it to your question please.